# Custom Sorting on Custom Field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my app, I have defined a custom field to represent a physical quantity using the [quantities](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/quantities) package.

```
class AmountField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def to_python(self, value):
        create_quantities_value(value)
```

Essentially the way it works is it extends CharField to store the value as a string in the database

```
"12 min"
```

and represents it as a quantities object when using the field in a model

```
array(12) * min
```

Then in a model it is used as such:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField()
    amount = AmountField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['group', 'amount']
```

My issue is that these fields do not seem to sort by the quantity, but instead by the string.

So if I have some objects that contain something like

- {"group":"A", "amount":"12 min"}
- {"group":"A", "amount":"20 min"}
- {"group":"A", "amount":"2 min"}
- {"group":"B", "amount":"20 min"}
- {"group":"B", "amount":"1 hr"}

they end up sorted something like this:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.all()
[{A, 12 min}, {A, 2 min}, {A, 20 min}, {B, 1 hr}, {B, 20 min}]
```

essentially alphabetical order.

Can I give my custom AmountField a comparison function so that it will compare by the python value instead of the DB value?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to sort it as numbers.  I mean no effective way since I believe Django allows sorting by computational field somehow but you have to compute all the keys to do that.  So try to find a way to store numbers as numbers in database.  Maybe store quantity as an integer and add method or property for conversion it to quantity object?  Something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()  # or PositiveIntegerField

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['group', 'amount']

    def amountAsQuantityObject(self):
        return create_quantities_value(self.amount)

    # or as a property
    quantity_object = property(amountAsQuantityObject)
```

Comment: In that case, is it possible to have a custom django field store itself in the database as two columns (one column for amount, one for unit)? Even then, I'd like to be able to compare the python object, since this wouldn't allow for comparison between different units (minute and hour, e.g.)

Comment: There is a [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5929) about multi-column fields.  As a workaround: you could serialize quantity object using [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module.  And this is not very comfortable but you have to choose one measurement unit for one resource (time, weight, etc) if you want effective sorting.

Comment: I wonder if you're making it unnecessarily hard on yourself.  I understand you'd prefer to do a Python sort, but that requires you load everything from the database into memory first and then do the sort.  I would also strongly recommend not to store different units of the same type (time, distance, weight) in the database, it's just easier to store everything as e.g. minutes and work with that.

Comment: I do like this idea. There is only one instance where this won't work for me. I did subclass the Amount fields into several specific fields TimeAmountField, MassAmountField, VolumeAmountField. However for some fields, the input can be either a weight or a volume (6 grams vs. 1 cup), but those won't be mixed and have to be sorted, so I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you store it with leading zeros in the database?

E.g. "02 min"

That way it would sort correctly and when you parse it out again the leading zeros should not matter.

Comment: That's not really an option. First, I'm using the string representation of the [quantities](http://packages.python.org/quantities/user/tutorial.html) object, and I'd rather not have to edit that code. And even If i did, there would be an unknown number of leading zeros. I'm using it to store not just time, but anything. Could be 10000 lbs for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with a totally different approach.

Instead of having a custom field to store what is really time units, why not just store the time units?

For example, 02 minutes, should just be 02. You can either store as integer or, I think there is a TimeField that will allow you to store units in units of time.

You obviously want it to display so a human being can correctly understand that 02 really means 2 mins, so just write a custom filter in your form to deal with the mins or hrs or whatever you might want to add to the end.

This would have other benefits. Let's say you wanted to add all those time units as you had it previously. To do so would require some string processing, and to change that portion of the string to something that has **add** or **sub** or the like methods.